# Java - Reflection: Get fields belonging to current class only

Tags: java, class, reflection, field

How can I get the fields associated only with the current class instead of all of its parent classes as well?

```
public class BaseClass()
{
     public int x = 0;
}

public class AnotherClass() extends BaseClass
{
     public int y = -1;
     public int z = -2;

     public void doStuff()
     {
          for(Field f : this.getClass().getFields())
          {
              //Save each field to a file
          }
     }
}
```

I want to get only Y and Z, which belong to AnotherClass. But the above gives me X as well.

This is meant to replace having to type each value that I want to save. It's not being saved in any typical format. It must be saved like this so don't suggest saving the fields in a different way.

Filtering out each field's name would defeat the purpose of this as there are well over 200.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get only the fields declared in the class with [getDeclaredFields.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields())  It will exclude inherited fields.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter based upon the `Field`'s `getDeclaredClass()`:

```
public static List<Field> fieldsDeclaredDirectlyIn(Class<?> c) {
    final List<Field> l = new ArrayList<Field>();
    for (Field f : c.getFields())
        if (f.getDeclaringClass().equals(c))
            l.add(f);
    return l;
}
```

This picks just `y` and `z` for your example.

Comment: Tee hee.  I tested `getDeclaredFields()` on the provided code sample and noticed it returning three elements, so rejected it as incorrect.  (Yes, that's easier than reading the documentation.)  However, I'd pasted the sample code as an inner class, and the third field wasn't BaseClass.x, it was the SuperClass.this$0 reference.  Reading?  Pah!

Answer (score 1):

There may be a cleaner way to do this with flags to some function, but an obvious answer (and what I've done in the past) is to find the difference between the `this.getClass().getFields()` and the `super.getClass().getFields()` arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Using public `Field[] getDeclaredFields()`

Returns an array of Field objects reflecting all the fields declared by the class or interface represented by this Class object. This includes public, protected, default (package) access, and private fields, but excludes inherited fields.

```
      Field[] fields = AnotherClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
      for(Field f : fields){
          System.out.println(f.getName());
      }
```